# Example from Wireguard's wg-quick man page: how can it work?

Tags: linux, networking, wireguard

This is from the Examples section of the man page for wg-quick:

```
A combination of the `Table', `PostUp', and `PreDown'
fields may be used for policy routing as well. For example,
the following may be used to send SSH traffic (TCP port 22)
traffic through the tunnel:

[Interface]
Address = 10.192.122.1/24
PrivateKey = yAnz5TF+lXXJte14tji3zlMNq+hd2rYUIgJBgB3fBmk=
ListenPort = 51820
Table = 1234
PostUp = ip rule add ipproto tcp dport 22 table 1234
PreDown = ip rule delete ipproto tcp dport 22 table 1234

[Peer]
PublicKey = xTIBA5rboUvnH4htodjb6e697QjLERt1NAB4mZqp8Dg=
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
```

This example seems incomplete to me. Shouldn't there also be an `ip route` specifying `table 1234` that would accomplish sending SSH traffic through the tunnel? I'm far from expert on Wireguard and routing, so maybe there's something going on behind the scenes that I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, wg-quick automatically adds routes via wg0 corresponding to the AllowedIPs of all peers on this interface. That's the whole purpose of the Table= parameter in your example.

(Although it also happens even if Table= is not specified – then routes are added to the main table. One would use Table=off to opt out of this behavior.)

Similar functionality also exists in systemd-networkd's WireGuard support but is opt-in (i.e. Table= must be specified even for the main table).

Comment: Thanks, @user1686. Am I correct in inferring that the example's introductory comment, "the following may be used to send SSH traffic (TCP port 22) traffic through the tunnel" means ONLY SSH traffic will be tunneled? If I inserted a `not` into the rule, would that result in sending all traffic EXCEPT SSH? Would this scheme work whether or not AllowedIPs include a 0.0.0.0/0?

Comment: Assuming wg-quick is still used, if you use a more specific AllowedIPs, then wg-quick will only insert more-specific kernel routes as well. The policy rule will still force all SSH traffic to be *checked against* table 1234 at first, but only destinations that match will be sent through wg0, whereas destinations that didn't match a route will just fall through to the next policy rule that checks the 'main' table.